# Java program freezes after short time on rapsberry pi without error

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, freeze

so I'm working on a program to turn on or off my hue lights as I enter my room. At my roomdoor are 2 HCSr04's mounted to detect the direction of the incoming person. The program works mostly fine but after a short period of time it just freezes and nothing happens. It's running on a Rapsberry Pi 3 with Raspbian.

Here is the code:

```
public class Distance {
    //GPIO Pins
    private static GpioPinDigitalOutput sensorTriggerPin;
    private static GpioPinDigitalInput sensorEchoPin;
    private static GpioPinDigitalOutput sensorTriggerPin1;
    private static GpioPinDigitalInput sensorEchoPin1;
    int f = 0;
    ZoneId id;
    public static double distance2;
    public static double distance3;
    public static boolean left = false;
    public static boolean right = false;
    public static long timeleft;
    public static long timeright;
    public int counter;


    final static GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        ZoneId id = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");


        int hour = 22; //LocalDateTime.now(id).getHour();
        if (hour > 18 || hour < 7) {

        } else {
            System.out.println("Hour not in estimated working time");
            System.out.println("Hour:" + hour);
        }

        sensorTriggerPin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_00); // Trigger pin as OUTPUT // rechts von Schrank aus
        sensorEchoPin = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN); // Echo pin as INPUT

        sensorTriggerPin1 = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_27); // links von Schrank aus
        sensorEchoPin1 = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_25, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);

        new UltraHue();
        UltraHue.hue();

    }
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {


        do {

            Thread.sleep(20);
            Double Distance = getdistance(sensorEchoPin, sensorTriggerPin);
            //int hour =22;     //LocalDateTime.now(id).getHour();
            // && hour>18 || hour<7 
            if (Distance < 70 && distance2 < 70) { //rechts vom Schrank             

                if (right == false) {
                    right = true;

                }
                if (right == true && left == true) {
                    UltraHue.lightson(PHHueSDK.getInstance().getSelectedBridge());
                    right = false;
                    left = false;
                    counter = 0;
                }

            }
            distance2 = Distance;

            Thread.sleep(30);


            double Distance1 = getdistance(sensorEchoPin1, sensorTriggerPin1);
            int hour1 = 22; //LocalDateTime.now(id).getHour();
            // && hour>18 || hour<7 
            if (Distance1 < 70 && distance3 < 70) { //links vom Schrank

                if (left == false) {
                    left = true;

                }
                if (right == true && left == true) {
                    UltraHue.lightsoff(PHHueSDK.getInstance().getSelectedBridge());
                    right = false;
                    left = false;
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }

            distance3 = Distance1;


            if (left == true || right == true) {
                counter = counter + 1;
                System.out.println(counter);
                if (counter == 70) {
                    System.out.println("resetting counter");
                    left = false;
                    right = false;
                    counter = 0;
                }
            } else {
                counter = 0;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public static double getdistance(GpioPinDigitalInput sensorEchoPin3, GpioPinDigitalOutput sensorTriggerPin3) throws InterruptedException {
        sensorTriggerPin3.high(); // Make trigger pin HIGH
        Thread.sleep((long) 0.01); // Delay for 10 microseconds
        sensorTriggerPin3.low(); //Make trigger pin LOW

        while (sensorEchoPin3.isLow()) { //Wait until the ECHO pin gets HIGH

        }
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(); // Store the current time to calculate ECHO pin HIGH time.
        while (sensorEchoPin3.isHigh()) { //Wait until the ECHO pin gets LOW

        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime(); // Store the echo pin HIGH end time to calculate ECHO pin HIGH time.
        double distance = (((endTime - startTime) / 1e3) / 2) / 29.1;
        return distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really hard to help you with your problem. The code is rather long and messy (lots of commented out code and german comments all over). Also we can not check how you connected the Raspberry to the sensors. You could try to install [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) and connect to the remote program running on the Raspberry. With VisualVM you can observe the running program and maybe find out which method is blocking your program. Usually if your program freezes it is stuck in an endless loop. Check your while loops maybe?

Comment: Find out the PID of the java process and do a `kill -3 [PID]`. The JVM will dump its Thread dump on STDOUT (so you migth redirect that into a file). That way you can see what each thread is doing down to the class and line number.

Comment: BTW: `Thread.sleep((long) 0.01);// Delay for 10 microseconds`. Casting a `float` value `0.01` to `long` results to the value `0`, not `10`. Simply pass `10` if you want to wait 10 milliseconds. Maybe that's the reason for the "hang" because it's possible that `sleep(0)` has the same effect as `wait(0)`: An infinite wait.

Comment: Just guessing - how long will `while (sensorEchoPin3.isLow()) {  } //Wait until the ECHO pin gets HIGH` this loop? Wouldn't it be rational, to sleep for a - maybe very small - time, to avoid overheating of the cpu and maybe let the GC do some work? I don't know how fast the gpio-signal may rise, how fast you need to react. and how many time this loop is executed before such states change.

Comment: That could be the whole point. Maybe sometimes the reflection of the ultrasonic sensor doesn't get to the sensor so the program waits for the ultrasonic and gets stuck there. Gonna try it out tomorrow. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think your code can be simplified a lot. E.g. why are you using variables like distance1 and distance3, their purpose is not clear to me. I have rewritten your code to a more simple and readable version. Try to run the code and if it fails, surround it with a try catch block and check the stacktrace. Be careful with while loops such as

```
`while(sensorEchoPin3.isLow()){ //Wait until the ECHO pin gets HIGH

 }
 while(sensorEchoPin3.isHigh()){ //Wait until the ECHO pin gets LOW

 }`
```

Are you sure the pins will return to low or high state eventually? Also try to not create variables inside the thread run method, create them outside the loop and reference them. They are memory heavy.

```
public void run() throws InterruptedException {
    while(true){
        sleep(20);
        //int hour =22;     //LocalDateTime.now(id).getHour();
        // && hour>18 || hour<7
        if (getdistance(sensorEchoPin, sensorTriggerPin) < 70) {       //rechts vom Schrank
            right = true;
            if (left) {
                UltraHue.lightson(PHHueSDK.getInstance().getSelectedBridge());
                reset();
            }
        }

        sleep(30);
        if (getdistance(sensorEchoPin1, sensorTriggerPin1) < 70) {           //links vom Schrank
            left = true;
            if (right) {
                UltraHue.lightsoff(PHHueSDK.getInstance().getSelectedBridge());
                reset();
            }
        }

        if (left || right) {
            //System.out.println(counter);
            if (counter++ >= 70) {
                //System.out.println("resetting counter");
                reset();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void reset(){
    counter = 0;
    left = false;
    right = false;
}

private static long endTime;
private static long startTime;
public static double getdistance(GpioPinDigitalInput sensorEchoPin3, GpioPinDigitalOutput sensorTriggerPin3) throws InterruptedException{
    sensorTriggerPin3.high(); // Make trigger pin HIGH
    Thread.sleep((long) 0.01);// Delay for 10 microseconds
    sensorTriggerPin3.low(); //Make trigger pin LOW

    while(sensorEchoPin3.isLow()){ //Wait until the ECHO pin gets HIGH

    }
    startTime= System.nanoTime(); // Store the current time to calculate ECHO pin HIGH time.
    while(sensorEchoPin3.isHigh()){ //Wait until the ECHO pin gets LOW

    }
    endTime= System.nanoTime(); // Store the echo pin HIGH end time to calculate ECHO pin HIGH time.
    return(((endTime-startTime)/1e3)/2) / 29.1;
}
```